# Метрика дополнительных маршрутов получаемых по dhcp

Tags: linux, openwrt

У Билайна по эзернет dhcp-сервер даёт локальные адреса 10..., маршрут по-умолчанию и несколько локальных маршрутов для своих серверов. Маршрут по-умолчанию даёт только ограниченный доступ к dns и ещё каким-то их серверам. Чтобы получить интернет нужно поднять поверх эзернет L2TP-соединение. При этом чтобы сохранить старый дефолтный маршрут и так чтобы он не мешал новому, для первого соединения установлена метрика 1.

/etc/config/network:

```
config interface 'wan'                
    option _orig_ifname 'eth1'    
    option _orig_bridge 'false'   
    option ifname 'eth1'          
    option proto 'dhcp'        
    option hostname 'dlink'    
    option rebind_domain 'beeline.ru'
    option metric '1'                

config interface 'beeline'
    option proto 'l2tp'
    option server 'tp.internet.beeline.ru'
```

Проблема в том что у дополнительных маршрутов метрика так же становится =1, и они перебиваются новым дефолтным маршрутом с метрикой 0.

```
0.0.0.0         194.186.120.19  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 l2tp-beeline
0.0.0.0         10.119.49.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth1
10.119.49.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
10.255.255.250  10.119.49.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
10.255.255.253  10.119.49.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
194.186.120.19  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 l2tp-beeline
```

В результате билайновские серверы оказываются недоступны при поднятии интернета.

Вопрос как бы назначить метрику только первому дефолтному маршруту не трогая дополнительные для сетки 10?

Comment: А зачем вам вообще дефолт из 10 сети, если он не используется при работе в интернете. Не знаю как конкретно в конфигах openwrt, но настроками dhcpcd на линухе не проблема запретить поднимать дефолт. И сделать 0 метрику у dhcp. И вы уверены, что l2tp вам необходим ? У меня знакомый на билайте ... как то у него были проблемы с l2tp он позвонил в поддержку и они ему сказали где что нажать на их сайте, что бы перевести себя на прямое подключение без l2tp (реальник выдается по dhcp)

Comment: @Mike У нас прямого пока нет. Дефолт нужен на случай отключения l2tp для доступа к личному кабинету.

Comment: А если метрика одинакова, l2p не заменяет дефолт своим ? И если метрику одинаковой сделать и в настройки интерфейса "beeline" вписать option pppd_options 'replacedefaultroute' ? Я хз возьмет он ее от туда или нет и поддерживает ли тамошний pppd эту опцию, но вдруг прокатит :)

Comment: Если метрика одинакова, дефолт заменяется, а при закрытии соединения не восстанавливается

Comment: поставь метрику в 0, убери получение дефолта и добавь скрипт в пост-ап на добавление дефолта с отдельной метрикой

Comment: @eri не подскажите как добавить скрипт в пост-ап?

Comment: похоже через хотплаг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставил интерфейсам `wan` и `beeline` одинаковые метрики `1`. В результате default route в `wan` стирается при поднятии `l2tp`, остальные маршруты имеют приоритет перед новым интерфейсом с той же метрикой, так как они более конкретные. Чтобы сохранить старый default route, поправил `/lib/netifd/dhcp.script` добавив строки в конец функции `setup_interface()`:

```
setup_interface () {
    proto_init_update "*" 1
    proto_add_ipv4_address "$ip" "${subnet:-255.255.255.0}"
    # TODO: apply $broadcast
    local i j

    for i in $router; do
        proto_add_ipv4_route 0.0.0.0 0 "$i"
    done

    # CIDR STATIC ROUTES (rfc3442)
    [ -n "$staticroutes" ] && set_classless_routes $staticroutes
    [ -n "$msstaticroutes" ] && set_classless_routes $msstaticroutes

    for i in $dns; do             # здесь было for dns in $dns -
        proto_add_dns_server "$i" # заменил на i, чтобы сохранить переменную
    done
    for domain in $domain; do
        proto_add_dns_search "$domain"
    done
    proto_send_update "$INTERFACE"

    # TODO
    # [ -n "$ntpsrv" ] &&   change_state network "$ifc" lease_ntpsrv "$ntpsrv"
    # [ -n "$timesvr" ] &&  change_state network "$ifc" lease_timesrv "$timesvr"
    # [ -n "$hostname" ] && change_state network "$ifc" lease_hostname "$hostname"
    # [ -n "$timezone" ] &&     change_state network "$ifc" lease_timezone "$timezone"

    for i in $router ; do
        ip route add default via "$i" dev eth1  proto static metric 2
        for j in $dns ; do
            ip route add "$j" via "$i" dev eth1 proto static metric 0
        done
    done
}
```

Тут же добавил прямые маршруты для dns-серверов.
Важно, что команды `ip` стоят после `proto_send_update`, т.к. до неё интерфейс ещё не поднят.